# Test static methods with Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

We have a javascript class with some static methods.

```
export default class TestUtils {
  
  static test1() {
    return 42;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to write tests with mocha, but I stucked. My test looks like here:

```
const TestUtils = require("path to TestUtils");

describe("TestUtils", function () {
  it("test1 returns 42", function () {
    expect(TestUtils.test1()).is.equal(42);
  });
});
```

But by running this I get an error:

```
TypeError: TestUtils.test1 is not a function
```

Do you have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's kind obvious, but I hope it will help someone else.
The solution was to use following import

```
const {
  default: TestUtils,
} = require("path to TestUtils");
```